# Matrix / coordinate transformation in C#

Tags: c#, image, matrix, coordinates, transformation

I have an array of coordinates that reflect known positions on an image. Let's call this the template image. It has a unique barcode and orientation markers (which are also in the coordinate array).

The image is printed, scanned and fed back into my application to be detected. During printing and scanning, the image could be transformed in three ways; translation, rotation and scale.

Assuming that I can find the orientation markers on the distorted image, how can I use matrix transformation to get the relative positions of the remaining coordinates?

I posted this question on SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701448/image-transformation-in-c-sharp) but made it too complicated to understand what I wanted.

**EDIT**

```
namespace MatrixTest
{
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program
{
public static void Main ()
{
Template template = new Template(); // Original template image.
Document document = new Document(); // Printed and scanned distorted image.

template.CreateTemplateImage();

// The template image is printed and scanned. This method generates an example scan or this question.
document.CreateDistortedImageFromTemplateImage();
// Stuck here.
document.Transform();
// Draw transformed points on the image to verify that transformation is successful.
document.DrawPoints();

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName);
}
}

public class Page
{
public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
public Point[] Markers = new Point[3]; // Orientation markers: 1=TopLeft, 2=TopRight, 3=BottomRight.
public Point[] Points = new Point[100]; // Coordinates to transform in the TemplateScanned derived class!
}

// This class represents the originalk template image.
public class Template: Page
{
public Template ()
{
this.Image = new Bitmap(300, 400);

// Known dimentions for marker rectangles.
this.Markers[0] = new Point(10, 10);
this.Markers[1] = new Point(this.Image.Width - 20 - 10, 10);
this.Markers[2] = new Point(this.Image.Width - 20 - 10, this.Image.Height - 20 - 10);

// Known points of interest. Consider them hardcoded.
int index = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
this.Points[index++] = new Point((this.Image.Width / 10) + (x * 20), (this.Image.Height / 10) + (y * 20));
}

public void CreateTemplateImage ()
{
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(this.Image))
{
graphics.Clear(Color.White);

for (int i = 0; i < this.Markers.Length; i++)
graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, this.Markers[i].X, this.Markers[i].Y, 20, 20);

for (int i = 0; i < this.Points.Length; i++)
graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, this.Points[i].X, this.Points[i].Y, 5, 5);
}

this.Image.Save("Document Original.png");
}
}

// This class represents the scanned image.
public class Document: Page
{
public struct StructTransformation
{
public float AngleOfRotation;
public SizeF ScaleRatio;
public SizeF TranslationOffset;
}

private Template Template = new Template();
private StructTransformation Transformation = new StructTransformation();

public Document ()
{
this.Template = new Template();
this.Transformation = new StructTransformation { AngleOfRotation = 5f, ScaleRatio = new SizeF(.8f, .7f), TranslationOffset = new SizeF(100f, 30f) };

this.Template.CreateTemplateImage();

// Copy points from template.
for (int i = 0; i < this.Template.Markers.Length; i++)
this.Markers[i] = this.Template.Markers[i];

for (int i = 0; i < this.Points.Length; i++)
this.Points[i] = this.Template.Points[i];
}

// Just distorts the original template image as if it had been read from a scanner.
public void CreateDistortedImageFromTemplateImage ()
{
// Distort coordinates.
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Rotate(this.Transformation.AngleOfRotation);
matrix.Scale(this.Transformation.ScaleRatio.Width, this.Transformation.ScaleRatio.Height);
matrix.Translate(this.Transformation.TranslationOffset.Width, this.Transformation.TranslationOffset.Height);
matrix.TransformPoints(this.Markers);
matrix.TransformPoints(this.Points);

// Distort and save image for visual reference.
this.Image = new Bitmap(this.Template.Image.Width, this.Template.Image.Height);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(this.Image))
{
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
graphics.RotateTransform(this.Transformation.AngleOfRotation);
graphics.ScaleTransform(this.Transformation.ScaleRatio.Width, this.Transformation.ScaleRatio.Height);
graphics.TranslateTransform(this.Transformation.TranslationOffset.Width, this.Transformation.TranslationOffset.Height);
graphics.DrawImage(this.Template.Image, 0, 0);
}
this.Image.Save("Document Scanned.png");
}

public void Transform ()
{
// The rectangles of the ScannedDcoument are not known at this time. They would obviously be relative to the three orientation markers.
//    I can't figure out how to use the following code properly i.e. using Matrix to apply all three transformations.
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Rotate(-this.Transformation.AngleOfRotation);
matrix.Scale(1f/this.Transformation.ScaleRatio.Width, 1f/this.Transformation.ScaleRatio.Height);
matrix.Translate(-this.Transformation.TranslationOffset.Width, -this.Transformation.TranslationOffset.Height);
matrix.TransformPoints(this.Markers);
matrix.TransformPoints(this.Points);
}

public void DrawPoints ()
{
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(this.Image))
{
graphics.Clear(Color.White);

for (int i = 0; i < this.Markers.Length; i++)
graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, this.Markers[i].X, this.Markers[i].Y, 20, 20);

for (int i = 0; i < this.Points.Length; i++)
graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Purple, this.Points[i].X, this.Points[i].Y, 5, 5);
}
this.Image.Save("Document Fixed.png");
}
}
}
```

Comment: [this](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm)  may help you. Having 2 point s of start and 2 points of end, you *should* be able to get correct transform matrix.

Comment: @Tigran: The link appears to be broken. Actually the domain seems to be inaccessible at least from my location. Could you please provide an alternative?

Comment: @Rageel Khan: I just opened it.

Comment: Maybe it's a geo-IP restriction but I still can't access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to transform the image to the unit square ( (0, 0) - (1.0, 1.0))
You need three points, one is the origin, the other will be transformed to the x-axis (1.0, 0) and the other to the y-axis (0, 1.0).

In the original coordinate system:

- The origin is (Ox, Oy)
- The X-axis is (X1, Y2)
- The Y-Axis is (X2, Y2)
- X-Axis relative to the origin (X1-Ox, Y1-Oy) will be shortened to (RX1, RY1)
- Y-Axis relative to the origin (X2-ox, Y2-Oy) will be shortened to (RX2, RY2)

First we will shift the origin to (0,0) in homogeneous coordinates the transform matrix will be

```
(1   0   -Ox)
(0   1   -Oy)
(0   0    1)
```

The transform from the new space to the old one is represented by the following matrix:

```
(RX1   RX2   0)
(RY1   RY2   0)
( 0    0     1)
```

Because you want the inverse transformation, from old space to the new one, we need the invert this matrix:
Let's shorten (RX1*RY2-RX2*RY1) as D

```
(RY2/D   -RX2/D   0)
(-RY1/D   RX1/D   0)
(  0       0      1)
```

Now you can multiply both matrices first you do the translation and then use the second matrix to transform the basis.

Comment: With limited understanding of matrices, let me put it this way. We have an image with orientation markers `Rectangle r1, r2, r3`. The coordinates are known. Then we have multiple rectangles on the image as an array `Rectangle [100] = whatever.`. These coordinates are known as well. Now we receive a distorted copy of the same image and are able to detect the three orientation markers r1, r2 & r3. Based on that, we can get rotation angel, translation offsets and scale ratios. Continued in next message.

Comment: I can use `new Matrix.Rotate(rotationAngle, rect[100])` etc. but in what order. And how would each transformation affect the next? The end result: to get a transformed set of `Rectangle[100]` so I can read those areas of the distorted image.

Comment: I've added simplified code to the question. The method is `Document.Transform`. The transformation values are the ones detected. So calling the code 'as is' would apply the transformation twice over. I'm not sure whether to negate the values or what?

Comment: Is there an easy way to properly indent code in the SO editor?

Comment: I've added indenting. My visual studio uses spaces iso tabs so it's not a problem for me. You could also take a look at [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on meta stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks. I've also updated the code in the question. The result, however, is off in translation a bit. Looking at the code, any idea what could cause that? I suspect it has to do with your comment on sequence above. After all, rotation has to have a center of gravity right?

Comment: Yes, to summarize: negate rotation and translation, scaling is 1/(old scaling value). Then you need to apply the transformations in reverse order. You have the choice of reversing the transforms when you create your distorted image or later. This depends on how the translation is determined in the final version of your program.

Comment: Hmmm... That is an issue. Since this is an exmaple, I knnow the order of transformations. In a real-world scenario, I would need some logic to determine which order to perform transformations in. Although, by using non-matrix, image transofmrations, I have been able to get very accurate results ONLY is you redetect markers after each operation. That is very expensive and what I have been trying to avoid.

Comment: Since you've already answered my initial question, I'm creating a new one for my last comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834070/matrix-coordinate-transformation-order). Thanks.